# Echarts, how to use data series to switch color of line

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to use the data field to change the color of the line for a certain pice. Like when it is 1, it should be green, and when it is 2 it should be yellow. This snippet is only changing the color of the data point, not the line? Is there any chance to archive that with echarts?

```html
<html>
 <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="main_chart" style="width: 1200px;height:600px;"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  // based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main_chart'));

  var app = {};
  option = null;
  option = {
   xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['2012-03-01 05:06', '2012-03-01 05:07', '2012-03-01 05:08', '2012-03-01 05:09', '2012-03-01 05:10', '2012-03-01 05:11']

   },
   yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
   },
   visualMap: {
   show: false,
   dimension: 2,
   pieces: [
    {
    lt: 2,
    gt: 0,
    color: 'green'
   }, {
    gte: 2,
    color: 'red'
   }
   
   
   ]


  },
   series: [{


    data: [[1,37,1],[2,36,1],[3,36,2]],


    type: 'line',
    areaStyle: {}    
  

   }]
  };

  if (option && typeof option === "object") {
   myChart.setOption(option, true);
  }
 </script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this example
1) You should use the right dimension (xAxis, yAxis), for more info read documentation
2) If you want to color full area, please remove color: "aquamarine" from areaStyle, then it will be colorizate by pieces configs

```html
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="main_chart" style="width: 1200px;height:600px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    // based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main_chart'));

    var app = {};
    option = null;
    option = {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['2012-03-01 05:06', '2012-03-01 05:07', '2012-03-01 05:08', '2012-03-01 05:09', '2012-03-01 05:10', '2012-03-01 05:11']

      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
      },
      visualMap: {
      show: false,
      dimension: 0,
      pieces: [
        {
        lt: 2,
        gt: 0,
        color: 'green'
      }, {
        gt: 2,
        lt: 3,
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        gte: 3,
        color: 'yellow'
      }
      
      
      ]


    },
      series: [{


        data: [[1,37,1],[2,36,1],[3,36,2],[4,38,2]],


        type: 'line',
        areaStyle: {color: "aquamarine"}    
   

      }]
    };

    if (option && typeof option === "object") {
      myChart.setOption(option, true);
    }
  </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Ok, but I would like to have only 2 parts in the pieces, and make the difference which color the line has in the data series. Unfortunately this only works with the color of the data point and not with the whole line. Assuming I had 1000 data points and 500 times I would change the color, then the Pieces part would be quite bloated.

Comment: @selbolder I can't find any way to colorize lines by pieces for 3rd dimension.